# Dropzone not working after add 'defer' on js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, deferred

So I have a dropzone control and everything is working just fine.

Code below:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"  ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/dropzone.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/dropzone.js"  ></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">

                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#dZUploadPhoto").dropzone({
                        url: "/ashx/file-upload.ashx",

                        sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                            formData.append("type", "employee");
                        },
                        success: function (file, response) {
                        },
                        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png"
                    });
                });
          
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div runat="server" id="divFileUploadBackground">
            <div id="dZUploadPhoto" class="dropzone">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message">Click or drop photo here to upload</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

To speed up page load & eliminate render-blocking javascript files, I put 'defer' on every js file and add "DOMContentLoaded" on document.ready as per below:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/dropzone.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/dropzone.js" defer></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
               (function ($) {

                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#dZUploadPhoto").dropzone({
                        url: "/ashx/file-upload.ashx",

                        sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                            formData.append("type", "employee");
                           
                        },
                        success: function (file, response) {
                        },
                        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png"
                    });
                });
          
               })(jQuery);
           });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div runat="server" id="divFileUploadBackground">
            <div id="dZUploadPhoto" class="dropzone">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message">Click or drop photo here to upload</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now, my code is not working with 2 error message:

- Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
- Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.

I've been searching high & low and still don't get it. Can someone enlighten me and show me the way? Where i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you include the line:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

Inside the listener for the `DOMContentLoaded`, this delays the execution of this line to the point that, when its executed, the default `dropzone` auto discover feature and the default configuration have already been used.

Just move this line outside the listener:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

In fact `dropzone` also has a listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` and runs the auto discover when that event is fired, but since the `dropzone` library is registered first on that event it triggers before than your script, at least most popular browsers like chrome of firefox do it this way.